# Converting contour lines to terrain dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, 3d-analyst, terrain

I have downloaded free DEM from the NET and I generated a contour line with 10 meter for interval. So, I just want to convert the contour lines to LAS point file to create a new terrain dataset. Is this a correct way to create terrain dataset or not, if not what is the best way to create terrain dataset with a free data?

Comment: thank you very much @John Lindsay,in relation to your guideline for LAS file and LIDAR data,so is any way to make a terrain dataset with a free data from the NET, i have not LIDAR data.

Answer (score 6):

You can build a [terrain dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Building_a_terrain_dataset_using_the_New_Terrain_wizard/005v0000001p000000/) from points or lines as well as ASCII grids. No need to convert to LAS points, all you need is a multipoint feature class (which can be created from any of the above).

Comment: thank you very much @Martin, how can i convert lines to LAS points

Comment: You do *not* need to convert your lines to LAS points. Add your lines to your terrain dataset as they are! Follow the guide I linked and you should be fine!